# Atribuir valores de um select a uma variavel

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Bom estou montando um procedimento no MySQL, e dentro dele tenho o seguinte código:

```
  DECLARE valorConta DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE valorPGConta DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;

  SELECT Valor INTO valorConta
  FROM Contas
  WHERE Cod = CodConta;

  IF valorPGConta >= valorConta THEN
    
  ELSE
    
  END IF;
```

Bom declarei 2 variáveis sendo elas `valorConta` e `valorPGConta`.
Na tabela `Contas` tenho os 2 campos `Valor` e `ValorPG`.

Preciso saber como atribuir os valores nas 2 variáveis para depois fazer a verificação no `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro tem que declarar o **CodConta**, depois faça dois "**SELECT INTO**":

```
--RECEBE CodConta para realizar o filtro
DECLARE CodConta DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;

--VALOR CONTA
SELECT Valor 
INTO valorConta
FROM Contas
WHERE Cod = CodConta;

--VALOR PG CONTA
SELECT valorPGConta 
INTO valorPGConta
FROM Contas
WHERE Cod = CodConta;
```

O **IF** está correto, aí no caso é só executar os comandos desejados dentro do dele.

Comment: Acabei achando uma forma de fazer usando apenas um `select`. Assim: `SELECT Valor, ValorPG INTO valorConta, valorPGConta`

Comment: voce pode postar sua solucao para a sua pergunta.